# Cassandra (datastax-enterprise) repair error: Sync failed

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have three Datacenters with three nodes in each. When trying to run repair I get the following error:

```
ERROR [AntiEntropySessions:281] 2015-11-19 13:09:59,996  RepairSession.java:303 - [repair #ba0b5590-8ee8-11e5-8eb5-4b9679ec178d] session completed with the following er
ror
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.RepairException: [repair #ba0b5590-8ee8-11e5-8eb5-4b9679ec178d on entities, (4393112290973329820,4394202908924102592]] Syn
c failed between /10.x.x.xxx and /10.y.y.y
        at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairSession.syncComplete(RepairSession.java:223) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ActiveRepairService.handleMessage(ActiveRepairService.java:411) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
        at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairMessageVerbHandler.doVerb(RepairMessageVerbHandler.java:134) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:64) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Any idea?